# Remove ongoing notifications when IntentService is force closed

Tags: android

I launch an **ongoing notification** when in my **IntentService** when I do work with it, then I cancel that notification when work is done. The problem I'm facing is that the ongoing **notification persists even when the app is closed** (from the recents screen or force closed). How can **clean up** the notification in such cases?

Comment: How about clear notifications in `onDestroy()` method of IntentService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is force closed, your Service will receive the `onTaskRemoved(Intent)` callback. From here you can remove the notification.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent))